# Blocking Incoming IP With Win 7 Firewall

Tags: windows-7, ip, firewall, blocking

This question was asked before, but the answer is not working for me and the rules of this forum say do not respond to answers, so I am asking again. I went through the following process on the Win 7 firewall advanced tab wizard as advised in earlier post here:

```
1. On the first page choose Custom for the type of rule.
2. Click Next till you get to Scope and put the ip address in the remote IP section.
3. After that click Next to Action and choose Block the connection.
4. Click next till you get to Name and give the rule a name.
```

I get to step 3 and enter the IP(s) to block, but each time I click "next", or "action" in the left navigation pane, I get the error "You must specify endpoints for this rule". Can't find any info on specifying endpoints in the wizard or searching google. Appreciate if anyone can tell me what I am missing.  Thanks,  Roger

Comment: Did you choose "Inbound Rules" first in "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" before clicking "New Rule"? (`as advised in earlier post`... you could link to the previous post so we know what not to recommend.)

Comment: Did you leave "Local IP" at "Any IP"? If you choose "These IP addresses" you also need to provide the local IP, otherwise just leave it at "Any IP" (for local). If this doesn't help, could you provide a screenshot of that tab (Scope)?

Comment: Yes I chose "Inbound rules" and "New Inbound Rule" and "Any" for local IP, put IP under remote IPs. I went through the process a few times yesterday with same resulting error.  That said, this morning, after reading your post and starting over, to collect screen captures, it worked? I did close and re-open the firewall, no reboot, but I figure I must have been doing something wrong and just not seeing it.  I am a bit embarrassed. Thanks much for your reply. - Roger

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I may NOT have been in "Inbound Rules" before clicking "New Rule". I definitely was this morning and worked exactly as expected. Thanks again - Roger

Comment: @Rik I think [that's](https://superuser.com/questions/788640/blocking-incoming-ip-with-win-7-firewall#comment1027584_788640) worth a "real" answer -- that's certainly what I just did incorrectly. If you'd rather not, I can slap it in as a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I see the issue is already resolved some time ago but I will repeat the correct steps here again. I'm missing the selection of `Inbound Rules` in the steps. If you're not in the `Inbound Rules` when you're selecting `New Rule...`, or follow the steps below correctly, you might end up with the error `You must specify endpoints for this rule`.

So in the `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security` do the following:

- Choose `Inbound Rules` at the left pane
- Choose `New Rule...` at the right pane or from `Actions`
- step `Rule type`: Choose `Custom` and press <kbd>Next</kbd>
- step `Program`: Leave `All programs` selected and press <kbd>Next</kbd>
- step `Protocol and Ports`: Leave protocol at `Any` and press <kbd>Next</kbd>
- step `Scope`: Choose `These IP addresses` for `Which remote IP ...` (second block)

  - Press <kbd>Add</kbd> and type the IP to block and press <kbd>OK</kbd> and press <kbd>Next</kbd>
- step `Action`: Choose `Block the connection` and press <kbd>Next</kbd>
- step `Profile`: Leave all selected and press <kbd>Next</kbd>
- step `Name`: Give the rule a meaningful name and press <kbd>Finisch</kbd>

Now you can close the `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`and all inbound traffic from that IP-address will be blocked.